# Задача №3850. Сжатие списка

Tags: python-3.x, list

Дан список целых чисел. Требуется “сжать” его, переместив все ненулевые элементы в левую часть списка, не меняя их порядок, а все нули - в правую часть. Порядок ненулевых элементов изменять нельзя, дополнительный список использовать нельзя, задачу нужно выполнить за один проход по списку. Распечатайте полученный список.

Входные данные:

Вводится список чисел. Все числа списка находятся на одной строке.

Выходные данные:

Выведите ответ на задачу.

Мой код:

```py
s = input().split()
for i in reversed(range(len(s))):
    if s[i] == '0':
        s.append(s.pop(i))
print(*s)
```

Однако на одном из тестов мне пишут "Превышено максимальное время работы". Что не так?

Comment: Зачем использовать reversed если можно сразу сделать range(len(s)-1, 0, -1)

Comment: @Эникейщик, тогда при 0 0 0 0 9 программа выдаст 0 9 0 0 0, а надо 9 0 0 0 0

Comment: Тогда замените в функции 0 на -1. Очень просто, не так ли.

Comment: @Эникейщик, уже пробовала, все равно на одном из тестов превышает максимальное время выполнение программы....

Comment: Вытаскивание элемента из середины списка это очень «дорогая» операция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение медленное, так как вы удаляете элементы из середины массива. Это операция медленная - все элементы после удаляемого нужно сдвинуть на одну позицию влево. Это долго если массив длинный. Говоря высоким слогом ваше решение работает за квадрат. А можно сделать решение за линию.

Классическое решение задачи состоит в том что по массиву `a` бегут два индекса `i` и `j`. `i` перебирает все элементы, `j` от него отстает на каждом нуле. Если элемент не нуль, то он копируется с позиции `i` в позицию `j`.

Когда цикл окончился, все ненулевые элементы собрались в начале массива. В конце мусор, который мы заполняем нулями:

```
def move_zeros_2(a):
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] != '0':
            a[j] = a[i]
            j += 1
    for k in range(j, len(a)):
        a[k] = '0'
```

На Питоне не принято делать циклы по `range(len(...))`. Код ниже лучше соответствует языку:

```
def move_zeros_3(a):
    j = 0
    for v in a:
        if v != '0':
            a[j] = v
            j += 1
    for k in range(j, len(a)):
        a[k] = '0'
```

Comment: Только если в списке нулей нет или они в конце - будут просто лишние операции присваивания элементов списка. И у вас получается, грубо говоря, не один проходи по списку из-за необходимости отдельного зануления. Вы проходите все элементы в первом цикле и потом ещё раз проходите часть списка.

Comment: Циклы по `range(len(`  - вполне нормальная штука, если внутри цикла реально нужен доступ к элементам по индексу.

Comment: @CrazyElf, трудно придумать случай когда `enumerate` не делает всё что нужно.

Comment: @xmikex, согласен с вами. К каждому индексу массива делается два обращения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой код.

snz - это флаг, который значит, что нужно искать ненулевое значение для свопа. j - индекс элемента, с которым надо сделать своп ненулевому элементу. То есть при появлении первого элемента с нулевым значением происходит сдвиг всех ненулевых элементов именно к индексу j, после все нулевые значения просто пропускаются, а для ненулевых происходит своп на индекс с j и увеличение этого индекса.

```
s = list(map(int, input().split()))
snz = False
i=0
while (i<len(s)):
    if s[i]==0 and not snz:
        snz=True
        j=i
    while s[i]==0 and i < len(s)-1:
        i+=1
    if snz and s[i]!=0:
        s[j],s[i]=s[i],0
        j += 1
    i+=1
print(*s)
```

Comment: Что такое `snz`? И хорошо бы описать принцип работы вашего кода.

Comment: добавил в ответ.

Comment: Ну я плюс вашему ответу сразу поставил, хотя алгоритм даже с пояснением до конца не понял )

Comment: смысл алгоритма - найти первый нулевой элемент, а потом пропускать остальные нулевые элементы - так как они интереса не представляют уже, а все ненулевые элементы обязательно будут сдвинуты из-за того, что был найден первый нулевой элемент - поэтому мы делаем своп на первый нулевой элемент и потом увеличиваем индекс j.  То есть неважно где будут все последующие нули в исходной последовательности - мы просто нашли место, куда начинать складывать ненулевые элементы и оно от последующих нулей никак не меняется - нули просто пропускаем, а все ненулевое переносится по индексу j.

Comment: там в общем можно было флаг snz не вводить, а просто проверять на наличие значения у j. snz - search non zero

Comment: `0 1 2` -> `1 0 2`.

Comment: условие внешнего while было неправильное - нужно было до len(s) перебор делать.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, в ответе xmikex имелось в виду что-то похожее на мой ответ, но я не совсем разобрался в его коде, мой код мне кажется гораздо понятнее, я понимаю, что он делает.

```
s = list(map(int, input().split()))

j = len(s) - 1
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == 0:
        while j > i:
            if s[j] == 0:
                j -= 1
            else:
                s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
                j -= 1
                break
        else:
            break
print(*s)
```

Просто храним справа индекс последнего элемента, который может быть не нулём. А слева идём по списку и когда находим подходящий нулевой элемент для обмена, то ищем справа наоборот ненулевой элемент - и меняем эти элементы местами. Таким образом первый и второй индекс постепенно сходятся в одну точку, получается ровно один проход по списку. И список используется один. Из списка при этом нет удалений и нет вставок, есть только обмен, поэтому скорость не страдает.

В исходном же коде из вопроса непонятно зачем нужен `reversed`, идти по списку в любом нужном направлении можно и не переворачивая предварительно список. И удаление через `pop` откуда-то из середины списка - это очень затратная операция. Добавление в список - тоже затратная операция (хотя, наверное, менее затратная, чем удаление). Если длина списка в итоге должна остаться неизменной, то лучше не обойтись без удаления и добавления, это сильно сэкономит время работы алгоритма.

Comment: у меня просто ищется индекс первого нулевого элемента, а потом все нулевые остальные элементы пропускаются, а ненулевые свопаются с этим индексом и индекс увеличивается на 1.

Comment: В условии задачи сказано "сохраняя порядок", а у вас `0 1 2` -> `2 1 0`. `2` и `1` поменялись местами.